# Split string and keep the separator

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I'm writing a chrome extension, and I need to split a string that contains only text and img tags, so that every element of the array is either letter or img tag. For example, `"a", "b", "c", "<img.../>", "d"`. I've found a way to do this: `str.split(/(<img.*?>|)/)`, however, some elements of the resulting array are empty (I don't know why). Are there any other suitable regexes?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: You could filter out the empty elements.

Comment: Do you have two image tags next to each other? That will put a blank entry between them.

Comment: Sample code:`"<img>fdsf<img>dasaadda".split(/(<img.*?>|)/)`. As you see, no blank entries. I know, I could filter out empty elements, but it's just interesting if there are other ways.

Comment: There are empty results because your regex has a null alternation.

Comment: Maybe, but what should I write instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get empty elements is the same why you get `<img...>` inyour results. When you use capturing parentheses in a `split` pattern, the result will contain the captures in the places where the delimiters were found. Since you have `(<img.*?>|)`, you match (and capture) an empty string if the second alternative is used. Unfortunately, `(<img.*?>)|` alone doesn't help, because you'll still get `undefined` instead of empty strings. However, you can easily [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) those out:

```
str.split(/(<img[^>]*>)|/).filter(function(el) { return el !== undefined; });
```

This will still get you empty elements at the beginning and the end of the string as well as between adjacent `<img>` tags, though. So splitting `<img><img>` would result in

```
["", "<img>", "", "<img>", ""]
```

If you don't want that, the filter function becomes even simpler:

```
str.split(/(<img[^>]*>)|/).filter(function(el) { return el; });
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. Well, it seems that there is no other solution except using filter so I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use exec instead of split to obtain the separated elements:

```
var str = 'abc<img src="jkhjhk" />d';
var myRe = /<img[^>]*>|[a-z]/gi;
var match;
var res= new Array();

while ((match = myRe.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(match[0]);
}
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Of course I can use exec, but I wanted to solve this task using split.